# Change my browsers POST method data

Tags: php, session, post

Is there any way to access My Own Browsers (IE8, FF3.6) Session data or POST Method data?
For example when an item is sending using POST method i can change it.

```
www.example.com/index.php?menuitem=2
```

change to

```
www.example.com/index.php?menuitem=3
```

Is there any script or software to help?

Comment: This should be posted on SuperUser.

Comment: Are you looking for mod rewrite perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). It will work across all browsers and will let you modify just about anything in the header.

Answer (score 1):

A firefox extension called [HTTP Request String Editor](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/211337/) enables you to edit the data sent to the server.

Note that you cannot change the session data itself, as it's stored on the server.